# How to add elements figureand figcaption in htmlpurifier?

Tags: php, element, figure, htmlpurifier

When i add image with params i have had ERROR

> ErrorException: Element 'figcaption' is not supported (for
>   information on implementing this, see the support forums)

my code

```
         'HTML.Allowed' => 'a[href],blockquote,br,del,em,figcaption,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,img[title|alt|src],li,ol,p,pre,strong,ul',

 .//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

        $config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');

        $config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);

        if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
            $def->addElement('figure', 'Block', 'Optional: (figcaption, Flow) | (Flow, figcaption) | Flow', 'Common');
            $def->addElement('figcaption', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common');
        }
```

Comment: Did you try switching around the order of your `figcaption` and `figure` definitions?

Comment: Actually, scratch that question. Your code works for me; I'm going to see if I can subtly break it to figure out what might be going wrong in your case and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. The order you're doing things in might be causing things to fail - make sure your application isn't trying to `purify()` before you're adding the elements. This example worked for me:

```
<?php

require_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$dirty_html = '<figure>
    <img src="/media/examples/elephant-660-480.jpg"
         alt="Elephant at sunset">
    <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href],blockquote,br,del,em,figcaption,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,img[title|alt|src],li,ol,p,pre,strong,ul');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
    $def->addElement('figcaption', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common');
    $def->addElement('figure', 'Block', 'Optional: (figcaption, Flow) | (Flow, figcaption) | Flow', 'Common');
}

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);

echo $clean_html;
```

This gave me `<figure><img src="/media/examples/elephant-660-480.jpg" alt="Elephant at sunset" /><figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption></figure>`.

Commenting out these lines:

```
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
    $def->addElement('figcaption', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common');
    $def->addElement('figure', 'Block', 'Optional: (figcaption, Flow) | (Flow, figcaption) | Flow', 'Common');
}
```

...gave me the error that you cite in your question, suggesting that by the time you're calling `purify()`, the code hasn't been executed yet.

If you tell us more about *where* in your application workflow you're trying to adjust the HTML definition, and where you're purifying, I might be able to help you troubleshoot the cause of your problem.